# Pass String to Download Video from URL using Retrofit

Tags: android, url, download, retrofit

As you can see above, I have given link of Video to download in a *static* way in `RetrofitInterface` class, as shown below:

```
@GET("/videos/toystory.mp4")
```

But, What If I have to pass Video links `dynamically`, for an example this string contains the link:

```
String strVidLink = ".....Vid Link.....";
```

Using Retrofit lib to download Video from URL, like this:

RetrofitInterface.class:

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @GET("/videos/toystory.mp4")
    @Streaming
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile();
}
```

DownloadService.java:

```
private void initDownload(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.html5videoplayer.net")
                .build();

        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> request = retrofitInterface.downloadFile();
        try {

            downloadFile(request.execute().body());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your downloadFile method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass link dynamically like below.

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @GET("/videos/{url}")
    @Streaming
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Path("url") String url);
}
```

or to call your interface like below.

```
Call<ResponseBody> request = retrofitInterface.downloadFile(/*Your Video url*/);
```